# Telegram боты: общаться с ботом при помощи апи

Tags: php, telegram

Всем известно, что в telegram можно создавать ботов, которые будут общаться с юзером, показывая ему различные кнопки.

Можно ли написать скрипт, который по апи будет общаться, как юзер, а не бот, внешне это будет выглядеть юзером, а на самом деле юзером будет притворяться нейросеть, имитирующая общение? Есть ли для этого методы апи?

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы эта нейросеть, имитирующая пользователя, сама подключалась к другим чатботамТМ и нажимала их кнопки для выполнения различных действий услуг/действий?

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно. Существует библиотека позволяющая реализовать задуманное на php: https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Пример использования:

```
        <?php

    if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
        copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
    }
    include 'madeline.php';

    $MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
    $MadelineProto->start();

    $me = $MadelineProto->get_self();

    \danog\MadelineProto\Logger::log($me);

    if (!$me['bot']) {
        $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => '@danogentili', 'message' => "Hi!\nThanks for creating MadelineProto! <3"]);
        $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@MadelineProto']);

        try {
            $MadelineProto->messages->importChatInvite(['hash' => 'https://t.me/joinchat/Bgrajz6K-aJKu0IpGsLpBg']);
        } catch (\danog\MadelineProto\RPCErrorException $e) {
        }

        $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => 'https://t.me/joinchat/Bgrajz6K-aJKu0IpGsLpBg', 'message' => 'Testing MadelineProto!']);
    }
    echo 'OK, done!'.PHP_EOL;
```

Также пример ее использования для написания telegram-клиента есть здесь https://habr.com/ru/post/433268/